# raster2pgsql loads raster into a single column

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql

I would like to load a raster (.asc) into my PostgreSQL Database. 
In order to demonstrate the problem I chose the raster downloaded from this homepage: https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/products/height_models/dhm25200

Here some info about my PostGIS_Version:

```
psql -U postgres -c "SELECT PostGIS_Version()"

    postgis_version
---------------------------------
2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

Let me give you some information about this raster with gdalinfo:

```
Driver: AAIGrid/Arc/Info ASCII Grid
Size is 1926, 1201
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (479900.000000000000000,302100.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (200.000000000000000,-200.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  479900.000,  302100.000)
Lower Left  (  479900.000,   61900.000)
Upper Right (  865100.000,  302100.000)
Lower Right (  865100.000,   61900.000)
Center      (  672500.000,  182000.000)
Band 1 Block=1926x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=193.000 Max=4445.019
  Minimum=193.000, Maximum=4445.019, Mean=1272.461, StdDev=800.094
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=4445.019
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1272.4613092273
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=193
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=800.09392403263
```

In order to load this .asc file I use this command in the command line:

```
raster2pgsql  -I -C -M "C:\Users\user\Downloads\data\data\DHM200.asc" -F public.dhmtest3 | psql -U postgres -d GIS_DB
```

To get this response:

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
CREATE INDEX
ANALYZE
HINWEIS:  Adding SRID constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding scale-X constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding scale-Y constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding blocksize-X constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding blocksize-Y constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding alignment constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding number of bands constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding pixel type constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding nodata value constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding out-of-database constraint
HINWEIS:  Adding maximum extent constraint
 addrasterconstraints
----------------------
 t
(1 Zeile)

COMMIT
VACUUM
```

That means, my raster was loaded to the DB. But looking in the DB, the raster is composed of only one column, with all the single raster values coerced together. Which means, this is not a raster but something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it should be.

It has loaded the raster in blocks. As specified by the block size.

The actual raster data is stored in the "rast" column. But each rast value is an actual raster. You can confirm this by checking the size of the rast objects.

For example:

```
select ST_Width(rast), ST_Height(rast) from raster_table where rid = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's how you sad, it works fine.

Comment: @LiKu if that helped you should accept the answer as correct by ticking the green tick mark next to my answer.